# MVC dropdownlist when a list of models is passed in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a model , in which there's a variable

```
public IEnumerable<string> MonthDropDown { get; set; }
```

In controller , I am filling this as:

```
var months = "Jan,Feb,March,April,May,June,July,Aug,Sept,Oct,Nov,Dec";
            ImportFiles inputfile = new AetnaCoventryMigration.Model.ImportFiles();
            inputfile.MonthDropDown = months.Split(',');
```

In the view, I am passing a list of myModels as a model , how can I create a drop down box for this list of months? The problem is I can't use `m => m.MonthDropDown` as my model in view is a list of my model class.

Kindly help!

I am also using the list of models , later in my view , so cannot pass just a model to the view , I am passing `Ilist<model>` to the view.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have 2 things:

**First** To edit a List of Model in a view, you can use the MVC2 way by Steven Sanderson : [Editing a variable length list, ASP.NET MVC 2-style](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/)

**Second** to implement the dropdown: you can do something like this:

```
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Month,
 ((List<string>)ViewBag.MonthDropDown).Select(option => new SelectListItem
 {
     Text = Html.DisplayTextFor(_ => option).ToString(),
     Value = option,
     Selected = (Model != null) && (option == Model.Month)
 }))
```

In the controller, fill the Month values in a ViewBag:

```
var months = "Jan,Feb,March,April,May,June,July,Aug,Sept,Oct,Nov,Dec";   
ViewBag.MonthDropDown = months.Split(',');
```